# ImageJ-display pixel value on image

Tags: imagej

I have a small image and I want to display each pixel value on the image in ImageJ instead of pointing each pixel and look at the value one by one. Is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [*Image ▶ Transform ▶ Image to Results*](https://imagej.net/docs/guide/146-28.html#sub:ImageToResults) command.